# Selecting duplicate XPath nodes based on multiple subnodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to make an XPath that selects the duplicate nodes in an XML file and outputs a text string containing them. The XML goes something like this:

```
<root>
  <Roles>
    <Role>
      <ALIAS> <!-- COMMENT 1-->
        <alias.src_id>LONDON</alias.src_id>
        <alias.tms/>
        <alias.id>0000012345</alias.id>
        <alias.id_type>CITY</alias.id_type>
      </ALIAS>
      <ALIAS> <!-- COMMENT 2-->
        <alias.src_id>LONDON</alias.src_id>
        <alias.tms/>
        <alias.id>0000099999</alias.id>
        <alias.id_type>PLACE</alias.id_type>
      </ALIAS>
      <ALIAS> <!-- COMMENT 3-->
        <alias.src_id>FRANKFURT</alias.src_id>
        <alias.tms/>
        <alias.id>000000001</alias.id>
        <alias.id_type>CITY</alias.id_type>
      </ALIAS>
      <ALIAS> <!-- COMMENT 4-->
        <alias.src_id>PARIS</alias.src_id>
        <alias.tms/>
        <alias.id>0000012345</alias.id>
        <alias.id_type>CAPITAL</alias.id_type>
      </ALIAS>
      <ALIAS> <!-- COMMENT 5-->
        <alias.src_id>LONDON</alias.src_id>
        <alias.tms/>
        <alias.id>0000012345</alias.id>
        <alias.id_type>CITY</alias.id_type>
      </ALIAS>
    </Role>
  </Roles>
</root>
```

As you can see, only comments 1 and 5 are really duplicated so I'd want it to return something like `"WARNING! Duplicated comment: LONDON - 0000012345 - CITY"`.

My first approach to selecting the duplicates was to select the subnodes individually:

`/root/Roles/Role/ALIAS[alias.src_id=following-sibling::ALIAS/alias.src_id][alias.tms=''][alias.id=following-sibling::ALIAS/alias.id][alias.id_type=following-sibling::ALIAS/alias.id_type]/alias.id/text()`

However, it would look for each subnode duplicate individualy, so it would detect all comments as duplicated because each subnode would also be present on some other node even if the rest in that node didn't match Then, I thought about concatenating the string values of the subnodes and comparing that instead:

`/root/Roles/Role/ALIAS[concat(alias.src_id,' - ',alias.tms,' - ',alias.id,' - ',alias.id_type)=following-sibling::ALIAS/concat(alias.src_id,' - ',alias.tms,' - ',alias.id,' - ',alias.id_type)]/alias_id/text()`

But even though some validators say it works, others say it isn't a valid XPath expression (Including the one I'm using this for)

I've been trying to get it to work modifying this and that but I feel like this approach is a dead end, I'm new to XPath so I can't come up with any other ways to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath finds the duplicate by looking at [`preceding::*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes#preceding) elements. XML parsing is sequential so it makes sense in this case to look back rather than look forward.

```
//alias.src_id[. = preceding::alias.src_id and following-sibling::alias.id = preceding::alias.id and following-sibling::alias.id_type = preceding::alias.id_type]
```